# The upload path does not appear to be valid in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter project assume 2nd_c in another CodeIgniter project assume 1st_c. i want to upload files and images to 1st_c project, but it throws path error "The upload path does not appear to be valid" i have load "upload" library, here is my code

```
$config=array();

                    $config['upload_path'] = '../assets/uploads/jobs';

                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';

                    $config['overwrite']     = false;

                    $config['max_size']      = 3000;

                    $config['remove_spaces'] = true;

                    $config['max_filename']   = 10;

                    $config['file_ext_tolower'] = true;


                    $this->upload->initialize($config);
                    
                    if($this->upload->do_upload('pic')){

                    $udata = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());                

                    $jobimage = $udata['upload_data']['file_name'];            

                    $data['j_image'] = $jobimage;     

                   }else{

                       $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();

                       echo "<pre>"; print_r($errors); echo "</pre>";

                       exit;

                    }
```

"../assets/uploads/jobs" this is in my 1st_c project , it works fine on localhost but on server it throws error. I have tried "FCPATH" but no luck.

Comment: did you check, if the upload path exists on the server?

Comment: is one site a subdomain on the other? Do you want to keep a copy on server A and ALSO server B?

Comment: What Webserver are you running on your PC under Localhost and what is the Webserver running on the "server". Something is different, so knowing that will help.

Comment: @Vickel yes it does

Comment: @Kinglish i have uploads folder in project A there is no folder of uploads in project B

Comment: try with base64 upload mathod

Answer (score 0):

Use `APPPATH` or `base_url()` when dealing with CI folders.

```
$file_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../assets/uploads/jobs');
```

or

```
$file_path = base_url().'/assets/uploads/jobs');
```

---

The folder structure should be

```
Application
assets
    uploads
        jobs
system
index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
              $upload_path = "Test_folder/Temp_folder";
              public function upload($upload_path,$name){
                  $config['upload_path'] = $upload_path;
                  $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
                  $config['max_size'] = 0;
                  $config['file_name'] = $name;

                  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                  $this->upload->initialize($config);

                  if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file'))
                  {
                      return "true";
                  }
                  else{
                      $file_data = $this->upload->data();
                      $file_name = $file_data['file_name'];
                      return $file_name;
                  }
                }
```